# Importação Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho essa importação e depois defino as colunas que eu quero. Eu consigo na propia importação definir as colunas que eu quero?

```
import pandas as pd 

data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/t714591/Videos/comissoes/95/96.txt",encoding='ISO-8859-1', sep=';')

data = data.iloc[:, [0, 1, 4, 5, 6]]

data.to_excel(r'C:/Users/t714591/Videos/comissoes/95/teste.xlsx', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, você pode usar o parâmetro `usecols`

Seu código ficará assim:

```
data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/t714591/Videos/comissoes/95/96.txt",encoding='ISO-8859-1', sep=';', usecols=[0, 1, 4, 5, 6])
```

Informação pode ser encontrada direto na documentação

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.